# MySql - group rows by time interval and average value

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a MySQL DB with rows with data taken every minute. I want to group these rows by 15 minutes taking an average value

I store date in as DATEFORMAT.

I have a query which group them by 1 hour, but i cannot get this work for 15 minutes

```
select machineId as machineId, 
       avg(value) as value,
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(LASTUPDATE),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS LASTUPDATE 
from Power 
WHERE machineId in (1,2) AND 
      str_to_date(LASTUPDATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) > str_to_date('2018-11-15 09:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
group by date_format( LASTUPDATE, '%Y%m%d%H'  ), machineId
```

Any idea?

Comment: Create a computed field that parses out the mins interval and group on that?

Comment: I advice you to read "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It almost seams more easy to generate a 15 minutes interval list (subquery) or a (temporary) table with the times and JOIN with those results..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to come up with a representation of the time with a 15 minute quantum.

```
 FLOOR(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(last_update, '%i') AS UNSIGNED)/15)
```

then convert back to minutes:

```
 15*FLOOR(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(last_update, '%i') AS UNSIGNED)/15)
```

Then put that in your query (simplified):

```
 SELECT machine
 , CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(last_update, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
    , LPAD(15*FLOOR(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(last_update, '%i') AS UNSIGNED)/15), 2, '0')
    ) AS timebin
 , AVG(value)
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY machine
 , DATE_FORMAT(last_update, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
 , 15*FLOOR(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(last_update, '%i')/15))
```

Comment: what is `CONCATENATE` function? i think you mean `CONCAT` here right? Besides i don't believe this query will work when the server is running on only_full_group_by sql mode..

Comment: Whoops autocorrect. And you are right about the compatibility mode. I've been switching it off since it was added. But if the op doesn't know how to identify and resolve the error message, he's in more trouble than we thought